# Vb.net .net Framework 1.0 how to access data from database and show in text box

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ado.net

I am using .net framework 1.0 in Vb.net Win form, The question is that how can Access the data from Database and show particular column and row in the textbox.
I show data in my Gridview but I want to show some data in lable and text box.

```
Public Dim ConnectionString As New SqlConnection( "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=WtfImaga;Integrated Security=True" )

Public  SqlDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter( "SELECT *   FROM wu.dbo.Students",ConnectionString )

Public  SqlDataSet As New DataSet

Public SqlcommandBuil As New SqlCommandBuilder(SqlDataAdapter)
```

And onclick I can show data which load on the GridView but I want to show Student name on a label

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

            SqlDataSet.clear()
DataGridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSet
DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing

        SqlDataAdapter.Fill(SqlDataSet ,"Students")
        DataGridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSet.Tables("Students")
   TextBox1.Text = SqlDataAdapter.Fill(SqlDataSet,"Students.StudentId")
    End Sub
```

Comment: suggestion book for vb.net database Access or article anything @ken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        SqlDataSet.clear()
         DataGridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSet
         DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing

         SqlDataAdapter.Fill(SqlDataSet ,"Students")
         DataGridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSet.Tables("Students")
         TextBox1.Text = SqlDataSet.Tables("Students").Rows(0).Item("StudentId")
End Sub
```

Show the student id from one of the rows in the dataset